# Place custom block below cart table?

Tags: magento2, cart, custom-block

I need to place a custom block below the cart table on the cart page in magento 2. At the moment I'm only able to place it above, so it's displayed above the table AND the cart summary sidebar.

[image: Where to place the block]

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add Below in your custom `checkout_cart_index.xml` layout file.

> app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
   <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Cart\Your\Block" name="custom.block" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/test.phtml" after="checkout.cart.form" />
    </referenceContainer>
```